# AWS Lambda | Severless provision concurrency trigger alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency, aws-sam

I created a lambda using AWS::Serverless:Function resource type in cloudformation by adding these lines to my resource:

```
  AutoPublishAlias: live
  ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig: 
    ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: !Ref ProvisionedConcurrencyCount
```

Which creates an alias called "live" and on each deploy a new version is published and live alias points at the new version.

The main issue is that I don't think that when the lambda is triggered it uses the latest version/the alias "live" that points at the latest version and hence the provisioned concurrrency is not being used.

How can I make sure that service like SQS or API Gateway that are attached to my lambdas and trigger the lambdas will trigger the version that being pointed by the "live" alias?

thanks!

Comment: Hey @Sharon, could you share an example on how you're integrating SQS or APIGW with your function? Whenever you configure these integrations, you need to use the ARN of the function alias, instead of the ARN that points to a specific version of your function.

Comment: Hi thanks @pgrzesik that what I did and it worked!
thank you